# Adding a field from a formset to add_error

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-admin

I Have following code in admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Timesheet
from .models import Action
import requests


class ActionAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Action
    extra = 0


class TimesheetAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ActionAdmin]

    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        instances = formset.save(commit=False)
        for instance in instances:
            url = 'https://xxx.xxxxxx.com/api.php'
            contents = requests.get(url)

            if contents.status_code == 200 and contents.json()['result'] == 'success':
                instance.ticket_title = contents.json()['subject']
                instance.save()
            else:
                form.add_error('?????', 'Ticket ID Not Found')
        formset.save_m2m()


admin.site.register(Timesheet, TimesheetAdmin)
```

I have ticket_id field in formset.If I pass 'ticket_id' this error will occur:

```
'TimesheetForm' has no field named 'ticket_id'.
```

Thats right, because ticket_id is not in the Timesheet form, but it is in the ActionForm Which is a formset in the Timesheet form.

What should I pass to the add_error for indicate this field?

Answer (score 1):

Having a look at the [add_error](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.add_error) docs, the method accepts two params:

```
Form.add_error(field, error)
```

> The field argument is the name of the field to which the errors should be added. If its value is None the error will be treated as a non-field error as returned by Form.non_field_errors().
>
> The error argument can be a simple string, or preferably an instance of ValidationError. See Raising ValidationError for best practices when defining form errors.

For your case, you must use it as:

```
if contents.status_code == 200 and contents.json()['result'] == 'success':
  instance.ticket_title = contents.json()['subject']
  instance.save()
else:
  form.add_error('ticket_id', 'Ticket ID Not Found')
```

Comment: @ArashMousavi add the code of `TimesheetForm` to the question. But it looks a design flaw for the way you need to bubble up those form errors.

Answer (score 0):

Update your save_formset function as below

```
def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
    instances = formset.save(commit=False)
    for instance in instances:
        url = 'https://xxx.xxxxxx.com/api.php'
        contents = requests.get(url)

        if contents.status_code == 200 and contents.json()['result'] == 'success':
            instance.ticket_title = contents.json()['subject']
            instance.save()
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError('?????', 'Ticket ID Not Found')
    formset.save_m2m()
```

It might solve you problem